# Model with a lot of fields with a clearly visible pattern: is a loop possible when declaring model fields?

Tags: django

**Django 3.1.6**

```
class RasterImage(models.Model):

    img_original = models.ImageField(upload_to=_raster_img_upload_to,
                                     verbose_name=" img_original", )
    img_100_100_webp_1x = models.ImageField(upload_to=_raster_img_upload_to,
                                            verbose_name=" img_100_100_webp_1x",
                                            null=True,
                                            blank=True,
                                            width_field="img_100_100_webp_1x_width",
                                            height_field="img_100_100_webp_1x_height")
    img_100_100_webp_1x_width = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    img_100_100_webp_1x_height = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    img_100_100_2x = models.ImageField(upload_to=_raster_img_upload_to,
                                       verbose_name=" img_100_100_2x",
                                       null=True,
                                       blank=True,
                                       width_field="img_100_100_2x_width",
                                       height_field="img_100_100_2x_height",)
    img_100_100_2x_width = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    img_100_100_2x_height = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Raster image")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Raster images")
```

For each picture I'll store a hundred of image files. The pattern of each field is clearl: width, height, device pixel ratio, webp or not. Then fields to keep width and height.

**The question**
Is it possible to organize such a model field set in a loop somehow?

P.S.: Don't persuade me to use django-imagekit or something. I'll keep process images locally.

Comment: You want to declare field automatically or assign values automatically?

Comment: Only to declare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `add_to_class`:

```
FIELDS = ["img_original", "img_100_100_webp_1x", "img_100_100_2x"] 

class RasterImage(models.Model):
    pass

for field in FIELDS:
    RasterImage.add_to_class(
        field,
        models.ImageField(
            upload_to=_raster_img_upload_to,
            verbose_name=field
        )
    )
```

Each attribute is then added to the new class object. This is done by calling `ModelBase.add_to_class` with the attribute name and object. This object could be something like a normal unbound method, or a string, or a property, or -- of most relevance here -- a Field subclass that we want to do something with. The `add_to_class()` method checks to see if the object has a `contribute_to_class` method that can be called. If it doesn't, this is just a normal attribute and it is added to the new class object with the given name. If we do have a `contribute_to_class` method on the new attribute object, this method is called and given a reference to the new class along with the name of the new attribute.

See [Installing The Attributes](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DevModelCreation#InstallingTheAttributes)

---

Or
You can use **[ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)**:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    img_original = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=_raster_img_upload_to, verbose_name=" img_original")
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class RasterImage(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Raster image")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Raster images")
```

Comment: It is the same manual organization. There is no loop here.

Comment: @Kifsif, you can use `add_to_class`, see [Installing The Attributes](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DevModelCreation#InstallingTheAttributes). Just tested on my app, works well